How to use Thermal $\phi ^4$ Feynman rules?
First, three definitions/equations:
We have the Matsubara frequencies
\begin{equation}
 \omega _n =\frac{2\pi n}{\beta }
 \end{equation}
And we denote
\begin{equation}
 \omega _k^2 =k^2 +m^2 
\end{equation}
The Matsubara propagator (propagator in imaginary time) is
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
 \Delta _F(i\omega _n ,k) &= \frac{1}{\omega _n ^2 +k^2 +m^2 } \\
   &= \frac{1}{\omega _n ^2 +\omega _k ^2 }
 \end{split}  
\end{equation}
Now, the Feynman rules in momentum space for a scalar $\phi ^4$ thermal field theory (see, Le Bellac) are:

Draw all topologically inequivalent diagrams to a given order of perturbation theory.

Assign a factor of $\Delta _F(i\omega _n ,k) $ to every line of the diagram. (This is the thermal propagator for a free scalar theory)

Assign a factor (the first $\delta  $ is a Kronecker symbol)
\begin{equation}
  -\lambda \beta \delta  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{4} \omega _i  \right) (2\pi )^3 \delta ^{(3)} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{4} k_i  \right) 
  \end{equation}
To every vertex.

Integrate over every internal line with the measure
\begin{equation}
  T\sum_{n}^{} \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi )^3 }
  \end{equation}

Multiply by the symmetry factor.

There will be an overall factor $\beta (2\pi )^3 \delta ^{(3)}(0)=\beta V $.


With the above rules in mind, I have two questions:

What is the Kronecker symbol doing in rule 3? Yes, I mean Kronecker symbol. This is the exact terminology Le Bellac uses in his book. Is he talking about the familiar $\delta _{ij}$?

Consider the diagram:



According to rule 4, this diagram will have 3 summations, right? If so, are the matsubara frequencies in the 3 respective propagators related to each other in some way? Is this what the above Kronecker Delta is for?
